# C# String and string. Why is Visual Studio treating them differently?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I create a normal Console App with a normal Main entry point as follows

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

then select it in visual studio everything is fine..

[image]

However, if I write the code as follows...

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // note the capital S in String
        }
    }
}
```

then everything is not fine....

[image]

Does anyone know why is it not picking up the String[] but happy with the string[] please ?

*edit*: Extracting from comments, it appears to be a bug in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013. Presumably it's also present in earlier editions but appears to have been rectified in VS2015. It's not a problem per se, and as noted the code still compiles *and executes* with either string[] or String[] I'd be interested to know the cause of the bug in VS though. I'd imagine the property editor window isn't `Using System;` ?

Comment: I can reproduce this in VS 2013, but not in VS 2015

Comment: Just ignore. Your code will compile and work fine. Seems like a glitch in project property editor.

Comment: Can you elaborate why this would ever cause any trouble? It seems they have fixed it in VS 2015 though

Comment: It is a (very weird) bug present in VS 2012 too.

Comment: So does your code have `using System;` at the top and compile, or not? If it does, please include that in your question, as otherwise it's a big red herring. Also, does this actually cause issues? If you try to run the project, what happens?

Comment: You said in a separate comment "It's reproducible with or without `using System`" - those are very different situations, given that it won't *compile* without `using System`.

Comment: sorry yes, using System is definitely there in both string[] and String[] examples

Comment: Haha. Finally a difference between string and its alias

Comment: So... It's obviously still a valid entry point. Are we talking about a suspected bug in Visual Studios? I tried this change on my project and I couldn't reproduce.

Comment: I cannot remember where, but I have read that `String` is meant to be used for methods and `string` is used for string storage. But don't quote me on that lol

Comment: Side note: I find this hilariously funny that SkeetJon was edited by Jon Skeet. I feel like SkeetJon is a fanboy.

Comment: http://thoughtcatalog.com/justin-hook/2012/09/12-reasons-you-should-never-meet-your-hero/

Comment: Same bug (in VS2013) with cases like `Main(System.String[] args)` and `Main(global::System.String[] args)` and `Main(MyUsingAliasToSystemDotString[] args)` all of which are legal and compile without problem.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your example that uses `String` does actually compile?

Lowercase `string` is a keyword that is equivalent to using `System.String`; since your example doesn't import the `System` namespace, I expect it will cause compilation errors which might result in the project properties not being able to identify your Main method.

Add a `using System;` directive to the code file or explicitly use `System.String` instead of `String` to make the type known to the compiler.

Comment: It seems to work fine either way. But the behaviour showed in the picture (startup project recognised only with string) is actually happening (at least in VS 2012).

Comment: the example does import system. it compiles either way with string[] or String[]. edited question to show this

Comment: @Heyyou Thanks, I tried adding explicit steps to fix the issue; of course this answer is no longer relevant.